# Go compiler flag for conditional code

Tags: go, compilation

I am new to Go and as a former C++ programmer am a little confused on how to do this in Go.
I want to add a compile time flag based on which I may include some test code.

I tried using `-ldflags`, but am unable to go beyond a single variable.

This is what I tried: `-ldflags "X main.var1 var1_value" "X main.var2 var2_value"`.

Am I doing the right thing here?

Comment: Tests should go in a file with the `_test` suffix. Like this, they are excluded from regular builds but are compiled and ran by `go test`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [build constraints](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) instead of the `-X` flag. This, allows you to compile any code conditionally by doing something like

```
go install -tags 'foo bar'
```

If you still want to use the `-X` flag multiple times, do it like this:

```
go install -ldflags '-X main.Foo 1 -X main.Bar 2' main.go
```

or ([added and recommended](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/12795c02f3d6fc54ece09a86e70aaa40a94d5131) in Go 1.5+)

```
go install -ldflags '-X main.Foo=1 -X main.Bar=2' main.go
```